# Create array of objects from sorting another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array of objects, and the first elements from the each data object to be a separate object, the second element from the each data object to be another separate object and so on...

```
let array = [{   
    data: {
       center1: "1",
       storage1: "1",
       system1: "1",
    }
  },
  {  
    data: {
       center2: "2",
       storage2: "2",
       system2: "2",
    }
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    { center1: "1",  center2: "2"},
    { storage1: "1",  storage2: "2"},
    { system1: "1",  system2: "2"}
]
```

And this is what I tried do to but is not working really well:)

```
 const rows = [];
 array.forEach((item, index) => {
      for (let key in item.data) {
          rows.push({index : key + ': ' + item.data[key]});
      }
 });
```

The output is this:

```
[
    {index : 'center1: 1'},
    {index : 'storage1: 1'},
    {index : 'system1: 1'},
    {index : 'center2: 2'},
    {index : 'storage2: 2'},
    {index : 'system2: 2'}
]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That'll be incredibly brittle, given that key ordering in an object is technically irrelevant to a JS engine. Is there a reason why the keys are different for each object? Why aren't they all center/storage/system?

Comment: That doesn't really explain things: clearly your values _already_ capture those, so why are they not `{ center: 1, storage: 1, system: 1}`, `{center: 2, storage: 2, system: 2}` etc?

Answer (score 1):

This'll be incredibly brittle, because key ordering is irrelevant to how JS objects work, and the assumption that "the first key in each object is the same kind of key" is really only that: an assumption. So, the first thing to fix would be to make all those objects use the same keys, not uniques, thus making "key ordering" irrelevant.

However, if that's not an option (and it almost certain is, but *if* it's not) then [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will turn any object into a key/value array, which you can then use to restructure this data:

```js
let array = [{   
    data: {
       center1: "1",
       storage1: "1",
       system1: "1",
    }
  },
  {  
    data: {
       center2: "2",
       storage2: "2",
       system2: "2",
    }
  }
]

const restructured = array.reduce((result, e) => {
  Object.entries(e.data).forEach(([key, val], pos) => {
    if (!result[pos]) result[pos] = {};
    result[pos][key] = val;
  });
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(restructured);
```

Comment: And what if I have an array like this: let array = [{ data: { option1: "1", option1: "2", option1: "3", } }, { data: { option2: "4", option2: "5", option2: "6", } } ] The Output are the last items: {option1: '3', option2: '6'}

Comment: Then you'd have absolutely terrible data and you should do better, much like is already the case right now, just moreso. Your keys should not encode values. They should be "the name of the thing" and the value should be "the value for that thing", so you should strive for data that looks like `[{ center: ..., storage: ..., system: ... }, { center: ..., storage: ..., system: ...}, {...}, ...]` where the difference is _only_ in the values, not the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, which may probably optimized (of course it will work only if all objects strictly have the same structure) :

```js
  const array = [
    {
      data: {
        center1 : "1",
        storage1: "1",
        system1 : "1",
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        center2 : "2",
        storage2: "2",
        system2 : "2",
      }
    }
  ];

  const finalArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(array[0].data).length; i++) {
    finalArray.push({});
    array.forEach(arrayItem => {
      finalArray[i][Object.keys(arrayItem.data)[i]] = Object.values(arrayItem.data)[i]
    });
  }

  console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: No need for `Object.keys` and `Object.values` separately, given that `Object.entries` exists,

Comment: Right, I just saw your post which is absolutely brilliant

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [{   
        data: {
           center1: "1",
           storage1: "1",
           system1: "1",
        }
      },
      {  
        data: {
           center2: "2",
           storage2: "2",
           system2: "2",
        }
      }
    ]

     const rows = [];
     array.forEach(item => {
          Object.keys(item.data).forEach( (dt, i) => {
              if ( ! rows[i] ) { 
                  rows.push({});
              }
              rows[i][dt] = item.data[dt];
          });
     });
     console.log(rows)
```

Comment: And what if I have an array like this:
let array = [{   
        data: {
           option1: "1",
           option1: "2",
           option1: "3",
        }
      },
      {  
        data: {
           option2: "4",
           option2: "5",
           option2: "6",
        }
      }
    ]
The Output are the last items:  {option1: '3', option2: '6'}

Comment: because, the keys is same, and return the last of iteration.